# VScode + pipenv + pyenv in WSL : debugger not working with Python only for non-system Python version

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pipenv

I am experiencing a problem with VScode debugger after I try to create a Pipenv environment with a specific python version that is not my original system version (3.7.3)

```
pipenv install --python <version>
```

I can tell anyway that the environment is activated correctly and I can run (in and out of Vscode) any Python script and the Python version is consistent (tested with *pipenv run python --version*)

This is the error I encounter each time I have a pipenv environment with anything different than my original system 3.7.3 python:

[image]

But if I create a pipenv environment with my original python version 3.7.3 then all works fine with the debugger:

[image]

I tried many things but I am not sure if this is an issue with WSL or pipenv or pyenv with VScode, I suspect a bug but I am not too sure

I have
pipenv : 2022.6.7
pyenv  : 2.3.1-20-g572a8bcf
Vscode : 1.68.1
Python versions
3.7.3 -> system
3.8.13
3.9.13
3.10.4 -> Global

launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you attach your `launch.json` to your issue? I think there's an answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have just added also launch.json file content

Comment: I would like to add that I have installed a fresh WSL debian 11 distro and installed from the begginning: 
git
pyenv (no python previously)
pipenv

After that I installed several python versions via pyenv and ran again the same tests and all works (well besides VScode not launching pipenv shell but I believe that is a normal behavior). Unfortunately still I don't know what caused the issue on my original WSL

Answer (score 0):

Take a closer look at the upper left corner of your first picture.

Vscode prompted you to create a "launch.json". I don't think you created a "launch.json" in the workspace during your first debugging process. Please follow the prompts.